# Simulate iPhone environment in Firebug

Tags: iphone, firebug

Is there a way I can get Firebug or Firefox to send an iPhone user agent string to the browser, so I can debug the iPhone layout of my site more easily?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search for a User-Agent switcher extension and install that. One option is [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/).

More generally, you can look for an extension to let you manipulate generic HTTP headers, which would of course include the User-Agent. It looks like [Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) is up to this task.

Comment: What about `max-device-width`? Can you emulate this in Firefox? I tried making the window narrow but that had no effect.

Comment: You will have more luck asking a full question about that. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking about; I have more experience faking out the User-Agent than developing mobile applications. Since Mobile Safari renders differently from Firefox, anyway, why not just use Mobile Safari running in the iPhone Simulator?

Comment: I'm trying to use Firebug to debug the CSS... it's faster than making a change and refreshing the iOS simulator.

Comment: At the moment though I just disabled the conditional `@media only screen...` comment and debugging in FF, which is working OK.

Answer (score 2):

Try [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)! Then set your user agent to whatever you like, in the tools menu.

Comment: What about `max-device-width`? Can you emulate this in Firefox? I tried making the window narrow but that had no effect.